# JavaScript: Removing an element via "this.remove" doesnt always work, if the class exists multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This creates a button, moves it and then deletes it.
The problem is that if I do this in quick succession (like by calling `clickedCookie()` multiple times per second, it only deletes some of them.
The weird part is, that the console still displays the correct element. But one line later the code breaks. Tried it with `this.element.remove()` as well, but same outcome. Some get deleted some don't. Same with movement by the way. If I simply create them quickly enough, some do not get moved. So it probably has something to do with the DOM?

```js
    let maxIndex = 0;
        
        class cookie {
            constructor(index) {
                this.index = index;
                let element;
            }
            addToScreen = () => {
                document.body.innerHTML += `<button id="floatingCookieNum${this.index}" class="floatingCookie">I'm floating</button>`;
                this.element = document.querySelector(
                    `#floatingCookieNum${this.index}`
                );
                this.element.style.top = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 500)}px`;
                setTimeout(this.moveCookie, 500);
                setTimeout(this.deleteCookie, 1000);
            };
            moveCookie = () => {
                this.element.style.top = "50px";
            };
            deleteCookie = () => {
                console.log(this.element);
                this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
            };
        }
        
        function clickedCookie() {
            maxIndex++;
            let c = new cookie(maxIndex);
            c.addToScreen();
        }
        
        clickedCookie();
        clickedCookie();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += `<button id="floatingCookieNum${this.index}" class="floatingCookie">I'm floating</button>`;
```

you essentially rewrite the body's HTML thus re-rendering your buttons and remove your previous buttons. So taking it chronologically:

```
clickedCookie(); // you created the first button
clickedCookie(); // body HTML rewriting, oops, the first button is removed...
...
deleteCookie = () => {
    console.log(this.element);
    // oops, the first button is removed and has no parentElement (null)
    // Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
};
```

The solution could be `Element::insertAdjacentHTML()`:

```js
    let maxIndex = 0;
        
        class cookie {
            constructor(index) {
                this.index = index;
                let element;
            }
            addToScreen = () => {
                document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                  `<button id="floatingCookieNum${this.index}" class="floatingCookie">I'm floating</button>`
                );
                this.element = document.querySelector(
                    `#floatingCookieNum${this.index}`
                );
                this.element.style.top = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 500)}px`;
                setTimeout(this.moveCookie, 500);
                setTimeout(this.deleteCookie, 1000);
            };
            moveCookie = () => {
                this.element.style.top = "50px";
            };
            deleteCookie = () => {
                console.log(this.element);
                this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
            };
        }
        
        function clickedCookie() {
            maxIndex++;
            let c = new cookie(maxIndex);
            c.addToScreen();
        }
        
        clickedCookie();
        clickedCookie();
```

Though this feature is pretty fresh, so I would use the old `Document::createElement()`. As a bonus you don't probably need the `id` attribute to find your element on the page:

```js
        let maxIndex = 0;
            
            class cookie {
                constructor(index) {
                    this.index = index;
                    let element;
                }
                addToScreen = () => {
                    this.element = document.createElement('button');
                    this.element.classList.add('floatingCookie');
                    this.element.textContent = 'I\'m floating';
                    this.element.style.top = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 500)}px`;
                    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
                    setTimeout(this.moveCookie, 500);
                    setTimeout(this.deleteCookie, 1000);
                };
                moveCookie = () => {
                    this.element.style.top = "50px";
                };
                deleteCookie = () => {
                    console.log(this.element);
                    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
                };
            }
            
            function clickedCookie() {
                maxIndex++;
                let c = new cookie(maxIndex);
                c.addToScreen();
            }
            
            clickedCookie();
            clickedCookie();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Easy to understand the problem and solution.
I can't believe I didnt think about the implication of ${this.index} when recreating the html. 
I will try out both solutions now to see which fits my code better.